# How to hide certain elements on a page using jQuery

Tags: jquery, filter, faceted-search

I am trying to implement something that is similar to a faceted search. My data is a series of objects and relationships. The idea is that you click an object (in this case "95 Theses" and then the possibly relationships are displayed, in this case "author" and clicking the relationship shows the object that matches the relationship, in this case "Martin Luther".

My clicking of objects and relationsips (predicates) works fine. What I need to do is allow users to click an object or relationship and have all those that extend from it removed.

This is what I thought of adding when a object or relationship 'tag' is clicked (every time I add another object or relationship I increment the global attribute called 'level'):

```
if($(".objHolder,. preHolder").filter("[level>'"+level+"']").filter("[holderId='"+holderId+"']").length) 
{   
    $(".objHolder,. preHolder").filter("[level>'"+level+"']").filter("[holderId='"+holderId+"']").remove();
}
```

---

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="objHolder" objid="1" holderid="1" level="1">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="2">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="objItemRow" objid="1" holderid="1" level="1">
              <td class="objItem" objid="1" holderid="1" level="2" bgcolor="#eeeeee" nowrap="nowrap">95 Theses</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td><img src="images/right.jpg" alt="" height="10" width="16"></td>
      <td class="preHolder" level="2" holderid="1">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="2">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="preItem" level="3" subid="1" preid="1" holderid="1" bgcolor="#eeeeee" nowrap="nowrap">author</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td><img src="images/right.jpg" alt="" height="10" width="16"></td>
      <td class="objHolder" level="3" holderid="1">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="2">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="objItem" level="4" objid="3" holderid="1" bgcolor="#eeeeee" nowrap="nowrap">Martin Luther</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `$(".objHolder,. preHolder")` for selection two different classes into one array?

If yes, try `$(".objHolder").add(".preHolder")` and any way write `.` and class name (`preHolder`) without a space!